# Android Error:Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout No Check on the Target

Tags: android, timeout, apk

I getting the error when I try to debug any program on my android device

> > Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout

I have tried restarting, and extending the timeout in the DDMS
When I have to select a device there is an red X in the target field next to the numbers

I'm new to android development and I would appreciate any help

Comment: check the error message in the problem bar.

Comment: Have you turned on "debugging" in your device? If you are getting a timeout, it is because the program isn't seeing your device. From the commandline try running: adb logcat. If you device is connected, and readable by the computer, it will generate logs; otherwise, it will say waiting for device.